# ActionController::UnfilteredParameters error on using smart_listing gem in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smart-listing

i dont know  what causing this issue in my rails app. I am trying to apply smart_listing gem table sorting functionality on my sprint model.

[image]

sprint controller :

```
def index
  @sprints = smart_listing_create :sprints, Sprint.all, partial: "sprints/listing", default_sort: { number: "asc" }
  @sprint = Sprint.new
end
...
def permitted_params
  params.require(:sprint).permit(:number, :start_date, :end_date)
end
```

index.html.slim :

```
= smart_listing_render(:sprints)
```

_listing.html.slim :

```
- unless smart_listing.empty?
  table.ui.celled.table
    thead
      th.header = smart_listing.sortable "Number", :number
      th.header = smart_listing.sortable "Start Date", :start_date
      th.header = smart_listing.sortable "End Date", :end_date
    tbody
      - smart_listing.collection.each do |sprint|
        tr
          td.header
            = sprint.number
          td.description
            = "#{sprint.start_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")}"
          td.description
            = "#{sprint.end_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")}"

    = smart_listing.paginate
 - else
   p.warning No records!
```

I know that it would be some very small error but i am not able to figure that out in the pst 24hrs :/ and cant find any other similar issue on stackoverflow/any other blog.

thank you :)

Comment: It looks like you could be running into an issue with Rails 5 + smart_listing. Does this GitHub issue help at all? https://github.com/Sology/smart_listing/issues/134

Comment: aargh!  how did i miss that page , thank you very much sir, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's currently a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Sology/smart_listing/issues/134) about this.

> The following pull changes the behaviour of to_h for unpermitted
>   params -
>
> [rails/rails#28734](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/28734)
>
> This change causes array collections to fail when sorting with the
>   error "unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash".

One way people have fixed this issue is by doing the following:

> Doing `self.params = params.permit!` in the controller before `smart_listing_create` also seems to fix the problem.

I'd add one disclaimer here. `params.permit!` will permit all current and future parameters. One should be very careful when using it. [Read the official documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#permitted-scalar-values) for more information.